# Rails application to not redirect to HTTPS on specific controller and action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can my application not redirect to HTTPS on a certain controller and action ? In my case it's the `controller transaction` and `action update_payment`. I'm having loop redirect problem on production.

I've tried using the the gem `rack-ssl-enforcer` and putting the following in the `production.rb`:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, :except => [%r{update_payment$}], :strict => true
```

Still, it seems it's not working..

Answer (score 0):

redirect_to takes an options parameter.  One of the options you can pass in is protocol.  So you can do

```
redirect_to @todos_path, protocol: "http://"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm not redirecting to anything explicitly. I'm having redirect loop problem. It seems like my application always tries to redirect http to https. I've tried to set config.force_ssl to false and the configuration above in the question. I want my application to accept POST requests with HTTPin this route without redirecting to HTTPS.

Comment: did you restart your server after setting force_ssl to false?  you can also do "redirect_to @todos_path, protocol: request.protocol".  That will redirect you to the url with the protocol of the request.